# single column indexing vs multiple column indexing

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have to run 2 simple queries on a very large table consisting approximately 20 million rows.

Table columns are `id|user_id|earned_amount|created_at`

Query 1:

```
select user_id, sum(earned_amount) as total_earning 
from earning_history 
where user_id=XX;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT date(created_at) date, sum(earned_amount) as earning, count(id) as total_entry 
FROM `earning_history` 
where user_id=xx 
GROUP by date
```

I have to run the second query more than the first one. So Im thinking about indexing the `user_id` and `created_at` column;

Without indexing, it takes about 6-7 seconds to perform the second query. 
My question is,

1. Should I index only user_id column? Or should I index both `user_id` and `created_at` column?
2. Should I use multiple column index like => `ALTER TABLE earning_history ADD INDEX (user_id, created_at);` ?

Comment: maybe you can run some test, comparing time with no index, one index on user_id, and two indexes on user_id and created_ad, but i'm not sure index is really usefull for group by field : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445071/creating-indexes-for-group-by-fields

Answer (score 0):

You could use a composite index  both for accessing fast and reduce the access for data retrieving values  .  you could use the columns for where (user_id)  and the columns used  in select ..

but for column use in function or in calculated  columns the indexes  are normally used

anyqwey you should have some benefits using  and index on

```
create index my_index  on my_table ( user_id, id, created_at, earned_amount)
```

or

```
create index my_index  on my_table ( user_id,  created_at,id, earned_amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless `id` can be `NULL`, say `COUNT(*)` instead of `id`.  Then the optimal index for *both* queries is *this order*:

```
INDEX(user_id, earned_amount, created_at)
```

Both queries will use it as a "covered" index.  Both need `user_id` to be first -- to satisfy the `WHERE`.  The first query will use only the first two columns, with only a minor overhead due to the unused 3rd column.  The second query does not care which order the 2nd and 3rd columns are in, I picked this order to make a single `INDEX` work well for both.

Two separate, single-column, indexes will *not* be as efficient.  MySQL will probably use only one index, and it would be `(user_id)`.  It would then have to bounce between the BTree containing the index and the BTree containing all the columns -- in order to get at least `earned_amount`.  "Covering" avoids this bouncing.